# GitLab CE - user permissions

Tags: gitlab

We're confiding adopting Gitlab, so I'm doing some casual testing. Have 8.5.4 (CE) installed.

Wondering if it is possible to set it so that a user's push automatically triggers a merge request.  The idea is that we have some junior Devs (students) that we don't want to be able to automatically commit to master...we want a senior dev (staff member) to review the work and approve the merge request.

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab has branch protection, so as long as the junior devs are at "Developer" permission and your senior devs are "Master" or higher, you can do this for any branch. In fact, it's how `master` is configured by default.

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html

This can be configured on a repo-by-repo basis.